# Remove select tag with text input if user select the certain option which cascade that

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make that if user is select certain option(provided from database) only one value then the other option tag appear to select else for all rest of other options user have text box to enter the value. Something like the below-

```
     <tr>
      <td><span class="alert">* </span>Country:</td>
      <td><select name="country_id" class="medforminput" id="country_id" onchange="getState('select_state.php?country_id='+this.value)">
     <option value="Select Country">Select Country</option>
      <?php
       while($row4=mysql_fetch_array($coun1))
        { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row4['country_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $row4['country_name']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
     </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="alert">* </span>State</td>
<?php
if($row4['country_name']=="INDIA")
{?>
    <td id="statediv"><select name="state_id" class="medforminput" id="state_id" onchange="getCity('select_city.php?state_id='+this.value)">
    <option value="">Choose State</option>
     </select></td>
<?php else {
<td id="statediv"><input type="text" name="state_id" class="medforminput" id="state_id"/>
</td>
<?php }?>
     </tr>
```

I am getting nothing what wrong in the concept? 
I want to display select tag where user choose the "INDIA" else text box to enter the state.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that if they select "India" another select dropdown should appear, but any other selection should result in a text box?

Comment: @Matt yes if user select "INDIA" then you should have states of INDIA appear in dropdown to select else the text to input it

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an onChange event handler in javascript that tests the option selected, then either displays the dropdown or textbox in a dynamic div.

I'm going to use jQuery because it's a LOT less code.

Example:

```
<select name="country_id" class="medforminput" id="country_id" >
<!-- options go here -->
</select>

<script language="javascript">
    $("#country_id").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'India') { // put the country id here instead of string comparison
            $("#stateInput").html(getStates());
        } else {
            $("#stateInput").html("<input type='text' id='stateId' name='stateId' />");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please excuse the pseudocode - I didn't want to make it excessively long.

Comment: It would be helpful if you teach me with example. I hope i will get what i want to do......